# Received emails from previous domain owner

Tags: email, domain-name

I've recently bought a domain name which is written differently than an already existing domain name. That already existing domain is owned by a company.

I've set up a wildcard redirect for all emails addressed at my domain. However I started to receive emails that seem to be sent in error, and were meant for the other domain name.

I first thought people simply mistyped the domain name and thus the emails landed at my domain. But judging by the amount of mails I receive, and tho whom they are addressed to (employee-acronym@mydomain.com) and also the content of said mails (hotel booking confimations, plans, even bank statements!) I am pretty sure that the domain was previously owned by that very company.

Now I'm planing to contact said company and tell them that I happen to receive emails that were meant for them. My question is, do I have to fear any legal consequences if I do so? I will of course delete all the mails and I haven't forwarded them or so. But I've still received them and It's been quite a while since I received the first one.

For the record: None of the mails contained a clause that stated, that the content of the mail is confidential.

Another question: Are they allowed to demand a transfer of the domain back to them, even if I legally own it now?

Comment: You have no affirmative duty to tell them you are receiving these emails. Telling them that you are gives them evidence by which they can argue that the domain ownership should be transferred to them. I am not a lawyer but in these scenarios it is useful to consider he maxim that “no good deed goes unpunished”.

Comment: What is the problem? You will always get emails you don't want or need. Just setup filters to discard them.